# Send random value with curl to server

Tags: post, curl

Let's say I have an HTML form which looks like this:

```
<form method="post" action="anmeldung.fcgi" onsubmit="return chkForm()">
    <input type=text name="person">
    <input type=hidden name="id" value="1234"> <!-- this value is generated -->
    <input type=submit name="press" value="OK">
</form>
```

The value from id is generated by a mechanism which is not known to us and every time you visite the site it is an other value. Now let's say that the script, which collects the data checks if the id is correct and only then the rest of the code is called.

Is there a way with curl to send the data with the correct id to the server? So can I read it out from the page and send it to the server anyway? I think I have to use the same "instance" of the HTML file or something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like this would be a multi-step process, but could be scripted fairly easily.  First, you would use curl to do a GET to the URL of the form, like so:

```
curl http://hostname/path/to/form.html
```

Then, you would parse the content returned from the above GET request, to pull the value that is stuffed in the hidden id field.

Then, you would use curl to do a POST to anmeldung.fcgi, setting the form inputs to be posted, like so:

```
curl --data "person=xxx&id=1234&press=OK"  http://hostname/path/to/anmeldung.fcgi
```

Comment: Perfect thank you for this. But how can I temporary save the value in a variable?

Comment: My suggestion would be to script this, using a scripting language (such as PHP, perl, python, bash scripting, etc).  Any of these languages have the capability to run the curl command through a subshell, and read the results of the curl command back into a variable.  For example, in PHP, you can do this using shell_exec.  So, the PHP script would execute the first curl command by way of a subshell, store the result of the curl command in a variable, then parse this variable for the id value, then execute the second curl command.